# Media manager popup renders twice

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a problem with the popup of the media manager. This popup is shown when we want to select an image under Images and Links tab. On one of my site it shows up in a smaller window, the folders are positioned under each other and it renders twice. 
Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: Open the browser console and see if any errors are being shown. What exact version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Hi Lodder, I have opened it, everything loads and there are no errors, only this: Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you using the most up to date version of this browser? can you confirm the same issue occurs in other browsers? Also, as mentioned before, what exact version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.2.4, and yes, it occurs in chrome, firefox and IE also.

Comment: Would you be able to upgrade to Joomla 3.3.5?

Comment: Do you have any third party extensions installed, specifically content plugins out editor-xtd code?  If the upgrades like Lodder don't work I wonder if another extension is loading the modal behavior library with the default modal class listener and altered the iframe size settings.  Odd issue indeed tho

Comment: Hi Lodder! Yes I have upgraded, but it did not help!

Comment: Hi Brian! I am using jce editor, but I have tried with disbling it, it did not work either.

Comment: Which admin template are you using? Can you go to the backend / templates / then filter by "Location: administrator" and see which one is your default - starred?

Comment: Hi Ricardo!
I'm using isis, but the popup is the same with protostar. I tried that.